# Is it defined to use pax across filesystems?

Tags: linux, backup, unix, restore

If I wanted to backup a *nx system, am I correct that going across filesystem boundaries would be a no-no?  Would utilities like `pax` properly handle the jump across them or do I avoid it?  If avoid it, what is the best way to do so?

## Example 1

Say I had a directory structure like:

`/home/1/user1/dir1 -> /home/2/user2/shared_dir1`

Where `/home/1/` and `/home/2/` are separate mount points to different devices.

Can I just use the `pax` to recursively backup `/home/` correctly?

## Example 2

What about:

`/home/user1`

Where that path has a directory structure beneath plus a mount point `/home/mount`.

Can I just use `pax` to recursively backup `/home/` correctly?

Comment: Actually I can't see obvious reasons why backing-up at the file level across filesystem boundaries would be a no-go?

Answer (score 0):

A mount point appears in readdir() or stat() like any other directory; programs will automatically cross filesystems without even noticing that they've done so, unless explicitly told to *not* cross them. Because of that, crossing mount points is not something that needs to be defined for each program (unless it does something inherently limited to one file system, such as creating hardlinks).

Comment: Well, as `pax` recognizes hard symbolic links, I was more concerned if they would keep track of fs the file was on so that these links would be restored correctly.

Comment: Hard links, symbolic links, or symbolic links to hard links, or hard links of symbolic links?

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't understand what you meant @user1686.  Of course I would mean all of those.